# How to hold a modifier key so ahk sends keypresses to a different window

Tags: autohotkey

I'm pretty new to ahk.

Say I have two separate `vlc` windows open and playing videos.

If one of the vlc windows is active, then I want to be able to hold a key to make all keypresses go to the other vlc window.

ie if I press <kbd>Left</kbd>, then it sends <kbd>Left</kbd> to the active vlc window, but if I hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, then it sends <kbd>Left</kbd> to the other vlc window.

If no vlc window is active, then I don't want autohotkey to do anything.

This is so I can control two vlc windows without having to click and choose which one is active.

I looked up [GroupAdd](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm) hoping I could use a group that includes both vlc windows, but couldn't find a way to target specific vlc windows from the group to send keys to it.

edit: I got a very basic version working, but I feel it's pretty ugly. I would like a way to send any key that's pressed if you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to the other vlc window. Also this seems a bit unreliable in switching focus if you use it a few times quickly in succession.

```
GroupAdd, vlcgroup, ahk_exe vlc.exe
return

#IfWinActive ahk_exe vlc.exe
+Left::   ; shift-left
GroupActivate, vlcgroup, r
Send {Left}
GroupActivate, vlcgroup, r
return
```

Comment: I googled a bunch of stuff but didn't find any way to target specific windows in a group.

Comment: Please clarify "specific windows in a group", [edit] your question an make it an [mre] with 2 windows  , where the first window is reacting on the keys

Comment: With `groupadd` I can make a group of windows and minimize them all as a group for example, but I don't know how to target only specific windows in the group. Obviously I don't need ahk to send keypresses to the active window. So the minimal repoducible example doesn't need ahk at all. The whole point of the question is that I don't know how to get ahk to send keys to the other vlc window.

Comment: @Luuk I've added something about groups to the question.

Comment: @Luuk I managed to make a reproducible example but it doesn't do all I want.

Comment: Which keys exactly do you want to make this work with? There's lots of edge cases with different key names, so they have to handled in a special way. Also, should it work with key combinations? Like shift + ctrl + a would send ctrl + a to the second vlc window.

Comment: @0x464e If I could get the arrow keys (for seeking), ctrl + arrows (also for seeking), and pgup/pgdn (for next/prev video) working, that would be great. I would like it to be more reliable than the basic version code that I posted if possible, maybe there is a better way to target the other vlc window without the two `GroupActivate` commands each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach could be done like this:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe vlc.exe
+Left::
    WinGet, WindowList, List, ahk_exe vlc.exe
    BottomMostVlcHwnd := WindowList%WindowList% 
    ControlSend, , {Left}, % "ahk_id " BottomMostVlcHwnd
return

^+Left::
    WinGet, WindowList, List, ahk_exe vlc.exe
    BottomMostVlcHwnd := WindowList%WindowList% 
    ControlSend, , ^{Left}, % "ahk_id " BottomMostVlcHwnd
return

...

#IfWinActive
```

You'd write out each hotkey.
`WinGet, , List`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#List)</sup> returns a legacy pseudo-array<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm#pseudo)</sup> of hwnds to Vlc windows.
The last element in that array will be the bottom most window.
You can get the last element of a pseudo array via a dynamic variable trick `WindowList%WindowList%`.
Essentially you're accessing a variable named `WindowListN`, where `N` is the number for the last element in the pseudo-array.

Then `ControlSend`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)</sup> is used to send keys to the background window without the need to activate it.
And you refer to the background window by a window name like `ahk_id 0x1234567`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_id)</sup>.

---

Of course writing out the hotkey for each key is pretty repetitive, so we can do something much better:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe vlc.exe
+Left::
^+Left::
+Right::
^+Right::
+PgUp::
+PgDn::
    WinGet, WindowList, List, ahk_exe vlc.exe
    ControlSend, , % StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "+", "{") "}", % "ahk_id " WindowList%WindowList%
return
#IfWinActive
```

The hotkey definitions are just stacked on top of each other.
<sup><sub>(If there were even more definitions, a loop with the `Hotkey`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm)</sup> command could be nicer)</sub></sup>

`A_ThisHotkey`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey)</sup> will contain the hotkey that was used, and `StrReplace`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrReplace.htm)</sup> is used to automatically replace the `+` with a `{`.
And finally the closing brace `}` is appended to the end.

Comment: That's fantastic! Perfect, works great. Thanks so much. One question - is the final #IfWinActive necessary in the script? If so, what does it do?

Comment: It ends the context sensitive hotkey block. So other hotkeys below that wouldn't be context sensitive. Assuming you have no other hotkeys below those ones, it doesn't *really* serve a purpose, but really, keep it there since it kind of belongs there.

Comment: Now I actually realize that I had that problem in another one of my scripts, and that's why the hotkey wasn't working!